# HTTP POST request with specified port number

Tags: java, android, http, post, android-studio

I'm developing an Android App using JAVA in Android Studio IDE. I'm trying to send an HTTP Post request from my application to retrieve the response from the server as XML.

When I run

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("100.1.1.1");
```

It works without any exception but when I use a port in the URL like

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("100.1.1.1:8081");
```

the app warns me by "Unfortunately, App has stopped" and exits.

The real IP Addresses in this post have been replaced by 100.1.1.1

My Question is "why it doesn't work with Port number in URL?" and if there is a better way to get data from a web server by URL and Query Strings what is that way.

The URL that returns data as XML is like :

> 100.1.1.1:8081/?FindResults&Parameter1&Parameter2&Parameter3

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add port separately like in code below:

```
private static final int HTTP_PORT = 8081;

private static final String USER_AGENT_NAME = "http.useragent";

private static final String USER_AGENT_VALUE = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 1.1; en-us;dream) AppleWebKit/525.10+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.4 Mobile Safari/523.12.2";


protected DefaultHttpClient getHttpClient() throws KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException, 
NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException {
    if (httpClient == null) {

        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), HTTP_PORT));

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter(USER_AGENT_NAME, USER_AGENT_VALUE);
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        ThreadSafeClientConnManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);
    }
    return httpClient;
}
```

While making HTTP request be sure that port is NOT included more.

Answer (score 0):

With HttpPost, it works when you specify port number as part of http URL, like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://100.1.1.1:8081");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `HttpPost(URI)` constructor insted of `HttpPost(String)`. Think it will work.